# How to replace workspace:^ with workspace:* in pnpm?

Tags: node.js, npm, monorepo, pnpm, turborepo

I am using pnpm to manage packages. When I add a workspace dependency using `pnpm add shared-configs --workspace --filter package-b`, pnpm generates this in `package-b`'s package.json file:

```
"dependencies": {
    ...
    "shared-configs": "workspace:^",
    ...
},
```

However, I would like some way to have it automatically set the `workspace:*` in both the `package.json` and `pnpm-lock.yaml` files. How can I solve this issue?